# check distinct values in datarowview.row.itemarray other than empty string

Tags: c#, datarowview

I am getting datarowview through the following code

```
DataRowView s = grdSampleData.GetRow(grdSampleData.FocusedRowHandle) as DataRowView;
```

how can i check here that all values in s.Row.ItemArray is distinct. If value is null or empty string it should skip the distinct nature ie there can be multiple null values or empty string in ItemArray but no other same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use LINQ [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) to check the distinct:

```
 bool flag = s.row.ItemArray.Where(x => x != null)
            .Where(x => (x is string) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) x))
            .GroupBy(x => x).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

How it works:

To simplify, assume your item array has: [1, 1, 3, 3]. `GroupBy(x => x)` will group your array in two group:

```
[ [1, 1], [3, 3] ]
```

To know whether it is distinct or not, you just check whether any group has `Count` > 1, if yes, it is not distinct. Example in here is not distinct

Comment: Its working. could you please elaborate me how it is working. I just wanna know rather than copy and paste into my code